# Trust prediction towards various objects of social service

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

I am trying to implement a simple system for trust prediction in social networks. I wonder (since "my system" only performs trust prediction of one user towards another user) if it is common to use that kind of system to predict trust of a user towards some kind of different object of social service.

So, for example, I want to recommend some kind of music video to the user:  let's call him Jake. Should I run some simple algorithm - let's say counting how many users that Jake trusts "like" this video - and make my decision whether to display this video on that simple criterion, or should I treat this video as a separate object and perform a "classification process" that will determine a trust value for it?

Which approach is more common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can combine the two. That was done a while ago for a movie recommendation system. You can find more information, including Matlab code [here.](http://ntuzov.com/Nik_Site/Site_pages/Software_skills/Matlab.htm#matlab_movierec) Let me know if you have more questions.